# Do wireless cables exist?

Tags: usb, keyboards, bluetooth

Are there "cables" that are just 2 bluetooth dongles that will interact with each other? I am looking for one for a custom mechanical keyboard. USB type c would be the best, but I think anything would do. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt something like this exists, as both ends are going to need power to communicate with each other.

Comment: Wireless cables?? Devices like keyboards with bluetooth dongles exist that are power by the USB port on 1 side, and the keyboard has batteries on the other side.  Obviously you have to change the batteries every couple months unless you integrate a charging stand and lthium ion batteries.

Comment: Here's an Arduino based solution https://lifehacker.com/convert-any-usb-keyboard-to-bluetooth-with-a-diy-adapte-1786324129 and an off-the-shelf solution http://handheldsci.com/kb

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously buy 2 USB bluetooth 4 le dongles.

1. Gets power and CPU from the computer
2. Gets power from batteries, but you need some kind of CPU.

Designing your own and getting it produced will take a lot of effort and money to get a company to agree to produce said circuit.

From the needlessly overpowered but easy solution department.

The Raspberry PI 2 (add bluetooth dongle) or 3 (built-in bluetooth)

1. Hook up a BIG battery
2. Hook the keys in the typical 11x11 or 12x12 fashion to the GPIO pins
3. Write some code to do the translations and connect using the standard built-in bluetooth tools.
   In python should be very simple.
4. Under clock it to the max possible and disable as much as possible to increase a pitiful battery life to a usable one.